# DPDK OVS with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking

We are trying to install DPDK OVS on top of the openstack juno in Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.19 on single server. We are referring following steps for executing the same.

**https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/06/09/building-vhost-user-for-ovs-today-using-dpdk-200**

During execution we are getting some issues with ovs-vswitchd service as its getting hang during starting.

Output of command `./ovs-vswitchd --dpdk -c 0x0FF8 -n 4 --socket-mem 1024,0 -- --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log --pidfile=/var/run/op penvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid` is as below

---

```
AL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb rte_ixgbe_pmd
EAL:   Not managed by a supported kernel driver, skipped
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb rte_ixgbe_pmd
EAL:   Not managed by a supported kernel driver, skipped
Zone 0: name:<MALLOC_S0_HEAP_0>, phys:0x30400000, len:0xb00000, virt:0x7f2d1ba00000, socket_id:0, flags:0
Zone 1: name:<RG_MP_log_history>, phys:0x35400000, len:0x2080, virt:0x7f2d1b600000, socket_id:0, flags:0
Zone 2: name:<MP_log_history>, phys:0xe3ce00000, len:0x28a0c0, virt:0x7f2d09400000, socket_id:0, flags:0
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00002|vlog|INFO|opened log file /var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00003|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 24 CPU cores on NUMA node 0
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00004|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 24 CPU cores on NUMA node 1
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00005|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 2 NUMA nodes and 48 CPU cores
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00006|reconnect|INFO|unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connecting...
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00007|reconnect|INFO|unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connected
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00008|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports recirculation
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00009|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: MPLS label stack length probed as 3
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00010|ofproto_dpif|INFO|netdev@ovs-netdev: Datapath supports unique flow ids
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00011|dpif_netlink|ERR|Generic Netlink family 'ovs_datapath' does not exist. The Open vSwitch kernel module is probably not loaded.
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00012|dpif|WARN|failed to enumerate system datapaths: No such file or directory
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00013|dpif|WARN|failed to create datapath ovs-system: No such file or directory
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00014|ofproto_dpif|ERR|failed to open datapath of type system: No such file or directory
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00015|ofproto|ERR|failed to open datapath br-eth1: No such file or directory
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00016|bridge|ERR|failed to create bridge br-eth1: No such file or directory
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00017|bridge|INFO|bridge br-ex: added interface br-ex on port 65534
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00018|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: added interface tapb6327a6f-e3 on port 1
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00019|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: added interface br-int on port 65534
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00020|bridge|INFO|bridge br-ex: using datapath ID 0000be3137b62448
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00021|connmgr|INFO|br-ex: added service controller "punix:/var/run/openvswitch/br-ex.mgmt"
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00022|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: using datapath ID 000016d2ab534949
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00023|connmgr|INFO|br-int: added service controller "punix:/var/run/openvswitch/br-int.mgmt"
2015-11-24T13:14:12Z|00024|bridge|INFO|ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.4.90
2015-11-24T13:14:19Z|00025|memory|INFO|25200 kB peak resident set size after 10.3 seconds
2015-11-24T13:14:19Z|00026|memory|INFO|handlers:17 ports:3 revalidators:7 rules:9
```

---

- We tried setting up `echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages`, but couldn’t succeed.

Can you please help us in getting the things if we are missing any and causing ovs-vswitchd to stuck while starting?

Also, when we create vm in openstack with DPDK OVS, dpdkvhost-user type interfaces are getting created automatically. If this interfaces are getting mapped with regular br-int bridge rather than DPDK bridge br0 then is this mean that we have successfully enabled DPDK with netdev datapath?

Comment: No need to say "we" - it sounds so *un*professional...

Comment: Were you able to run the ovs 2.4 alongside without disturbing openstack OVS bridges and ports?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is around
"Not managed by a supported kernel driver, skipped".

You have to unassign the devices from kernel drivers towards e.g. uio drivers so that DPDK can use them.

For Ubuntu 16.04 the following will help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/DPDK.html#dpdk-config-dev.

Manually that can be done with `dpdk_nic_bind`.

From the `--help` output:

> To display current device status:
>
> ```
>    dpdk_nic_bind --status
> ```
>
> To bind eth1 from the current driver and move to use igb_uio
>
> ```
>    dpdk_nic_bind --bind=igb_uio eth1
> ```
>
> To unbind 0000:01:00.0 from using any driver
>
> ```
>    dpdk_nic_bind -u 0000:01:00.0
> ```
>
> To bind 0000:02:00.0 and 0000:02:00.1 to the ixgbe kernel driver
>
> ```
>    dpdk_nic_bind -b ixgbe 02:00.0 02:00.1
> ```